# Tried to install kernel 5.14.0-1055 but got an error

Tags: kernel

Tried to install kernel **5.14.0-1055** but got the error

`Internal Error, No file name for linux-headers-5.14.0-1055-oem:amd64`.

I was using **Synaptic Package Manager**. Other than that error, it appeared to install. But later when I rebooted the machine I found that the `initrd.img-5.14.0-1055-oem` file was not specified in the **GRUB** configuration file and did not exist in `/boot`. So I ended up booting the old image via GRUB.

Finally, I just removed the new kernel to fix the problem.

I'm not sure this is the right forum for this. If not maybe someone could point me to the correct one.

Comment: You didn't mention what is the OS and how you installed a kernel.

Comment: System:    Kernel: 5.14.0-1054-oem x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: N/A Desktop: Gnome 3.36.9 wm: gnome-shell dm: GDM3 3.36.3 
           Distro: Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Machine:   Type: Laptop System: LENOVO product: 21CBCTO1WW v: ThinkPad X1 Carbon Gen 10 serial: <filter> Chassis: type: 10 
           serial: <filter> 
           Mobo: LENOVO model: 21CBCTO1WW serial: <filter> UEFI: LENOVO v: N3AET69W (1.34 ) date: 12/05/2022

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add information. And you didn't mention how you installed the kernel.

Comment: The system info is provided above. I bought the laptop with Linux preinstalled.